org-refile-targets as a local variable
Is it possible to set org-refile-targets on a per-file basis?
A similar question was asked here. But it did not get any answers.
I am OK if it is set as a Local variable in the file or it is set up in config.el (I am using Doom Emacs) or some other mechanism.
It is just that I should be able to customize refile targets on a per-file basis.

It should be quite possible to set org-refile-targets as a file-local variable. See Specifying File Variables in the Emacs manual.

You can set org-refile-targets as a file-local variable.
For example, the default value of org-refile-targets is ((org-agenda-files :level . 1)). Here's an Org mode file which changes that default value for the file, using this mechanism:
* Tasks

** Section one
one

** Section two
two

* Refile under here

** Level 2

*** Level 3

* Code

Before adding the
local variable section below, the source block gives the default value. After adding the
local variable section, saving and closing the file and then reopening it,
it gives the new value:
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
org-refile-targets
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
((nil :level . 3))
:end:

Original value was:

#+RESULTS:
:results:
((org-agenda-files :level . 1))
:end:

* COMMENT File-locals

# Local Variables:
# org-refile-targets: ((nil :level . 3))
# End:

The new value asks org-refile to refile into the current buffer (that's what the nil means), inside a level 3 headline. Try refiling Section one and you'll see that it will be refiled under the Level 3 headline in the same file. That confirms that org-refile-targets has indeed the file-local value specified in the local variables section.

Thanks. This worked perfectly. Instead of nil, I added the name of the file that I wanted to include in "".
